# Unable to use a shared container between two C++ classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a shared container between two classes, one is a producer, other is the consumer. The shared variable is created using make_shared in a header file. My producer pushes data in to the queue attached to an integer key and consumer tries to pop/read it. But my implementation does not seem to work. Although there are no errors, the queue that I pushed data into, doesn't seem to hold any data when my consumer tries to read it. I have made this reproducible example to demonstrate my issue.

main.cpp

```
#include "foo_1.h"
#include "foo_2.h"

#include <iostream>

Foo1 foo1;
Foo2 foo2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::queue<shared_container> q;
    SharedContainer map = *g_map;
    // 1 is a pre-known key for this toy example, attach an empty queue
    map[1] = q;


    // inserts in queue, queue size = 1
    foo1.producer();
    // reads from queue, queue size must be 1, it's 0
    foo2.consumer();

    // inserts in queue, queue size must now be 2, it's 1
    foo1.producer();
    // reads from queue, queue size must be 2, it's 0
    foo2.consumer();

    return 0;
}
```

foo_2.h

```
#ifndef FOO_2_H
#define FOO_2_H

#include "shared_container.h"
#include <iostream>

class Foo2
{
  public:
    Foo2()
    {
    }

    static void consumer(void)
    {
        SharedContainer map = *g_map;
        // read queue at known key = 1
        auto node_q = &map[1];
        std::cout <<"[consumer] size of queue=" << node_q->size() << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif    // FOO_2_H
```

foo_1.h

```
#ifndef FOO_1_H
#define FOO_1_H

#include "shared_container.h"
#include <iostream>

class Foo1
{
  public:
    Foo1()
    {
    }

    static void producer(void)
    {
        SharedContainer map = *g_map;
        // place value at known key = 1
        auto node_q = &map[1];
        // add something to this queue
        node_q->emplace(45);
        std::cout << "[producer] size of queue=" << node_q->size() << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif    // FOO_1_H
```

shared_container.h

```
#ifndef SHARED_CONTAINER_H
#define SHARED_CONTAINER_H

#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>

struct shared_container {
    int x;
    shared_container(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
};

using SharedContainer = std::unordered_map<int, std::queue<shared_container>>;
inline std::shared_ptr<SharedContainer> g_map = std::make_shared<SharedContainer>();

#endif    // SHARED_CONTAINER_H
```

Compilation:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o test
$ ./test
[producer] size of queue=1
[consumer] size of queue=0
[producer] size of queue=1
[consumer] size of queue=0
```

Comment: `SharedContainer map = *g_map;` creates a copy of the map, you should use `SharedContainer &map = *g_map;` to use the original map.

Comment: Avoid global variables.

Comment: @mch oh wow, you are right..could you explain why it creates a copy? I was under the impression that I grabbed the pointer itself and then performed operations on it. In the solution, you suggested adding a `&` What does that indicate? A reference? I could also use `*` I guess ?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I understand, but I went this route because my producer/consumers are static members of their respective classes and cannot access object variables. I must admit I am not familiar with good design patterns. How can I go about refactoring this?

Comment: @rookie When you declare an object like `T foo = something;` you always create a new instance. C++ uses value semantics, which means the new object is always a copy of the initializer in some way. If you want to create a reference instead of a new object, use `T & foo = something;` instead.

Comment: Make them non-static member functions then,

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I would if I could, but I can't. hence looking for alternatives

Comment: A global variable is not an alternative. If you have a problem with member functions, ask a question about that problem.